# Toggle between sumif and sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data from different quarters (Q1 to Q4) and a `sumifs` formula that takes the selected quarter as a parameter. What if I want to sum data from the entire year (all 4 quarters)?

I can do an `if` statement nesting a `sumifs` if a quarter is selected or a `sumif` if Yr2021 is selected but is there a more elegant formula to toggle between the two?

Edit: thousands of rows, quarter in column M. Drop down with 5 options, 4 quarters and 2021. Current formula is a `sumifs` accounting for quarter. When user selects year option, formula returns 0 because column M is labeled Q1 to Q4.

Comment: You could use SUM with SUMIFS.

Comment: My fault, I wasn't clear. My data is only labeled Q1 to Q4, no year. Edit: oh, sum 4 sumifs? How does that look like?

Comment: No, wrap the SUMIFS in SUM and use brackets around your (multiple) criteria. Well, a screenshot of your setup would be really helpful here.

Comment: Right like `sum(sumifs(Q1)+sumifs(Q2)+etc)` but that will error since Q2-4 hasn't happened for the year?

Comment: No like `=SuMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Area,rng,{"Q1","Q2",...}))`

Comment: Time to learn `sumproduct` thanks!

Comment: I honestly think you're overdoing it and the original approach is easier.

Comment: I think nesting the IF inside the SUMIFS() might be a better option also, but hard to know without more information.

Comment: so if yr2021 is chosen you want to return the sum of all quarters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IF inside the SUMIFS like this:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,M:M,IF(Z1="yr2021","*",A1))
```

Z1 would be the location of the drop down.  if it equals "yr2021" it return all results otherwise it filters on the drop down.

Change A:A to your number data column to be summed.